# Deserialize json/yaml from binary stream which contains other data

Tags: python, json, serialization, yaml

Suppose I have a binary stream `stream` and I generate it as follows.

```
stream.write('lol'.encode())
yaml.dump(some_obj, stream)
stream.write('awesome'.encode())
```

Then do I have to write a custom parser of some sort for the stream or can I recover `some_obj` as follows.

```
stream.read(3)
recovered = yaml.load(stream)
stream.read(7)
```

If this doesn't work with yaml serialization, does it work with json serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want because the YAML parser consumes the complete stream even if you dummp an explicit end (`yaml.dump(some_obj, stream, explicit_end=True)` (which essentially insert `...\n` before `awesome`) and it also doesn't work when writing `---\nawesome` (the document separator). The YAML parser consumes the word `awesome`¹ both when you use `yaml.load()` as well as when you use `yaml.load_all()`.

The part up front works fine, so you can consider doing something like:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

file_name = 'test.comb'

some_obj = dict(a = [1, 2], b = {3: 42})

with open(file_name, 'w') as stream:
    stream.write('lol'.encode())
    yaml.dump(some_obj, stream, explicit_end=True)
    stream.write('awesome'.encode())


with open(file_name) as stream:
    assert stream.read(3) == 'lol'
    stream_data = ''
    while True:
        stream_data += stream.read(1)
        if stream_data[-4:] == '...\n':
            break
    recovered = yaml.load(stream_data)
    assert stream.read(7) == 'awesome'

print(recovered)
```

which gives (in Python2):

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': {3: 42}}
```

and the file contents are:

```
lola: [1, 2]
b: {3: 42}
...
awesome
```

I use a similar technique, but reading lines with `for line in stream`, which cannot be combined with normal `read()` operations, for files that have a YAML header with metadata, followed by normal text (non-indented so emacs can properly work on it).

---

¹ <sub>I consider reading past the end-of-stream marker (`...`) a bug in the Python YAML parser so I'll try and fix this in the next release.</sub>